# Right click to select a row in a telerik gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik-grid

As I mentioned in title, is there any way to select a row with `right click` in `Telerik radGridView` in C# win-forms application? I searched a lot but no success.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is for `WPF`, not for `winforms`.

Comment: Any answer or suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found The solution, maybe it be helpful for someone.
Here is The Code:

```
private void QueuTabP1TabContextMenu_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    QueuGrid1.ClearSelection();
    int index = this.QueuGrid1.Rows.IndexOf(this.QueuGrid1.CurrentRow as GridViewDataRowInfo);
    this.QueuGrid1.Rows[index].IsSelected = true;
    this.QueuGrid1.Rows[index].IsCurrent = true;
}
```